# How to break a long single column to multiple with formula in Excel 2016 for Mac?

Tags: microsoft-excel, mac, worksheet-function

I am using Excel 2016 on Mac and need to find a formula for moving specific number of raws to the next column (in the example below it is 650 but I that number will change):

#### Original

```
A1

A2

.

.

A650

.

A1300

.

A1950

.


A124600
```

#### New format needed

```
A1    |   A651   |  A1351

A2    |   A652   |  A1352

.     |   .      |   .

A650  |   A1300  |  A1950
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Above the new columns write the row number you want that column to start from (1,651,1351 etc).

In the new columns use the offset function:

```
= offset($a1, b$1-1,0)
```

As you drag down, it'll refer to the rows in order, but the reference to b1 (and c1, d1 etc) add an offset to further down the original list.

Example with spacings of 100:

[image]

Comment: Thanks but that function does not work (note I edited it to remove the space after the = sign) but Excel still throws an error. I am looking into the offset formula and found how to do a copy of the cells from A1 but not to move them

Comment: there were unnecessary "

Comment: yes, you were correct - thank you. Now this copies the cells but does not move them. Is there any way to accomplish that please? If not I will need to figure out how to have the original list on sheet1 and the "formula" on sheet2

Comment: after you've split the data using the formula, you can copy and using paste special select 'paste values' to paste the data without the formula. Then you can delete the original column, move your data around etc.